Ошибка AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'strip'. Как исправить? Использую python и telethon
Во время разработки бота на telethon, я столкнулся с такой ошибкой -
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'strip'. 

Ошибка в этой строке -
link = event.message.chat.strip()

Когда я меняю "chat" на "message", то он выдаёт такую же ошибку, но вместо "User" пишет "Message". Полный код по ссылке, так как не уместился в вопрос

А с чего вы взяли, что User и Message должны иметь метод strip()?

Всё. Нашёл решение проблемы. Там надо было написать не:
link = event.message.chat.strip()

а:
text = event.text
link = text.strip()

